# How to add space before and after the special characters in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

Hi I want to add a space before and after the special characters in the string

> Frozen/Chilled/Ambient (Please state)

I want the result like

> Frozen / Chilled / Ambient ( Please state )

Are there any possibilities to add the space in ruby regexp?

Comment: Please define "special character".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't need to use complex regex

You can make use of block syntax of `gsub`

```
"Frozen/Chilled/Ambient (Please state)".gsub(/\W+/) {|w| " #{w} "}
#=> "Frozen / Chilled / Ambient  ( Please   state ) "
```

If you want to remove the duplicate spaces you can use `squish`

```
"Frozen/Chilled/Ambient (Please state)".gsub(/\W+/) {|w| " #{w} "}.squish
#=> "Frozen / Chilled / Ambient ( Please state )"
```

**NOTE:**

- `\W` - matches any non-word character
- [**`squish`**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-squish) - Removes surrounding white spaces and change multiple spaces to 1

**EDIT:**

As per the comment if can also make use of `/[[:punct:]]/`

```
 [[:punct:]] =>  [!"\#$%&'()*+,\-./:;<=>?@\[\\\]^_`{|}~]
```

Comment: neat solution, I was not aware with `(/W+/)` fetch all special characters (poor me in REGEX) 1+ from me ;)

Comment: More specifically, it will match non-word characters, i.e. anything beside a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and underscore. A more specific character group like `/[[:punct:]]/` might be more appropriate.

Comment: Ahh that's a nice suggestion

Comment: "Don't need to use complex regex" shouldn't be an excuse to write an overzealous gsub with a block, writing too many spaces and later removing them with a Rails specific method. :-/

Answer (score 4):

Try **[String#gsub](https://apidock.com/ruby/String/gsub)**:

```
> sample = "Frozen/Chilled/Ambient (Please state)"
#=> "Frozen/Chilled/Ambient (Please state)" 
> sample.gsub!("/", " / ")
#=> "Frozen / Chilled / Ambient (Please state)"
```

**Note:** `gsub!` will override variable's value itself

### Update:

as per your comment you want to add space before and after each special characters:

```
> pattern = /[^a-zA-Z0-9|(|)|_|\s\-]/
> sample.gsub(pattern){|match|" #{match} "}
#=> "Frozen / Chilled / Ambient (Please state)"
```

**Note:**  `pattern` covers all special characters

Comment: i need to add space before and after for all special characters.like [, . / \ ? - _ = + ) ( * % ^ $ # @ !]

Comment: @MichealRaj you should update your question accordingly, it currently says "the special character" (singular).

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
sample = "Frozen/Chilled/Ambient (Please state)"
sample.gsub(/([^\w\s])/, ' \1 ')
```

It is getting everything is not  a `\w` (`\w` is `a-z, A-Z, 0-9` and the undescore `_`) or space `\s`. Then `gsub` replaces the element found by itself with space before and after.

Comment: You can even use `\0` to refer to the entire match.

Answer (score 4):

This might be a quick solution.

```
"Frozen/Chilled/Ambient (Please state)".split("/").join(" / ")
# => "Frozen / Chilled / Ambient (Please state)"
```

A few minutes after, Cary Swoveland will come and comment, "Hey son, there are enough string methods to solve this problem, your solution is quite ineffective" -))

For that case, below snippet uses string methods, and matches everythin except 
letters digit and space.

```
q = "Frozen/Chilled/Ambient (Please state)"
puts q.gsub(/[^a-zA-Z0-9. ]/){|s| " #{s} "}
#=> Frozen / Chilled / Ambient  ( Please state )
```

without blocks.

```
q.gsub(/([^a-zA-Z0-9.])/, ' \1 ')
#=> Frozen / Chilled / Ambient    ( Please   state )
```

Comment: Cary might also object that `gsub` doesn't need a block to perform that substitution ;-)

Comment: Cary might also object that the first method ignores `()`.